# Set all measurable real functions on $[0,1]$ with metric $\int_{0}^1 \min \{1,|f(t)−g(t)|\}dt$ is Fréchet without nonzero continuous linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning, linear-transformations

**Bounty Edit:**  *In the following, all the questions will be highlighted by a bold number and a text written in italics.*

I found the following statement in a book, and I am really struggling to see why it is true.

> *The set of all measurable real functions on $[0,1]$, metrized via the map $$(f,g)\mapsto \int_{0}^1 \min \{1,|f(t)−g(t)|\}dt,$$ is a Fréchet space on which there is no nonzero continuous linear functional. (Even the linear functional $f\mapsto f(0)$ is not continuous on this space).*

---

Regarding the very last statement in braces, I should have a proof of it.

> *Attempted Proof:*
>   Let $f=0$, i.e. for every $x \in [0,1], f(x) = 0$, and define $f_n$ as
>   $$ f_n (x):=
> \begin{cases}
> 1, & \text{ if } x \in [0, \frac{1}{n}],\\
> 0, & \text{ if } x \in (\frac{1}{n}, 1].\\
> \end{cases}$$
>   To see that $f_n \to f$, notice that, for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
>   $$ \begin{align*} d(f_n , f) &= \int_{0}^1 | f_n (t) - f(t) | \ dt \\
> &\leq \int_{0}^1 | f_n (t)| + |f(t) | \ dt \\ 
> &= \int_{0}^1 | f_n (t)|\ dt  + \int_{0}^1 |f(t) | \ dt \\
> &= \int_{0}^1 | f_n (t)|\ dt \to 0 \end{align*} $$
>   However, $f_n(0) \nrightarrow f(0)$, because for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n (0) =1$, while $f(0)=0$.

Concerning it, here there is my **first question**:

**1)** *Is the way in which I wrote the proof correct?*

---

Regarding the main statement, the things that have to be proved are two:

a) $\mathcal{M}$ (that denotes the set of all measurable functions on $[0,1]$) is a Frechét space (complete metric linear space);
b) there are no nonzero continuous linear functionals on $\mathcal{M}$.

Related to part (b) I found in Rudin's "Functional Analysis" (pp.36-37, section 1.47) a proof that the space $L^p$
with $0 < p <1$ behaves in the same way. Moreover, on the [wikipedia page on locally convex TVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space) I found that there is still another space that behaves similarly, namely $L_0$, i.e. the set of all measurable functions with distance function $$d(f,g):= \int_{0}^1 \frac{|f(x) - g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}dx.$$

---

Thus, here there are my **other questions**.

**2)** *Is it possible to prove part (a) in different ways, namely one less constructive, and another one more constructive, with an actual $f \in \mathcal{M}$ to which an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(f_n) \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ converge? If yes, how?*

**3)** *Is it possible to prove part (b) by showing that $\mathcal{M}$ is homeomorphic to $L_0$, which is homeomorphic to $L^p$ with $0 < p <1$, and then exploiting Rudin's proof? Are all those spaces actually homeomorphic? If yes, how?*

**4)** *If they are not homeomorphic, and we cannot use Rudin's proof, essentially, how do we prove the result, namely part (a) and part (b)?*

---

I am looking forward to any answer, because being self-thaught I am having some real problems concerning this result, and I have the feeling that grasping this proof (with the techniques involved) would help me a lot.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "we have that $f (0) = 0$" Not at all. Instead your task is to find some functions $f$ and $f_n$ such that $f_n\to f$ for this metrics, and yet $f_n(0)$ does not converge to $0$. Hint: Choose $f=0$ and assume that $f_n(0)=1$, how to make $d(f_n,f)$ small?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the hints. Just a point – and I am sure here there is a superhuge mistake and once I got it right, I will reach a sudden enlightment... –, I assumed $f(0) = 0$ because $f$ is seen as a linear functional, and for linear functional you always get it. Why is this wrong? (I am messing up things quite badly)

Comment: The linear functional $L$ mentioned in the post is the function $L:f\mapsto L(f)=f(0)$, which acts on every measurable function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$. Thus, the functions $f$ have no reason to be linear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this (indeed I was messing around). I was waiting to answer, because first I wanted to digest your hint properly, but I am afraid it could take a while. Maybe I will pop up again on this asking you for a feedback concerning what I came up with your hints. Really thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem at all with taking your time (in fact this is *much* better than the opposite).

Comment: @Did: First of all, again thanks a lot for your hints. I hope I made good use of them, because – as you can see – above I considerably edited the text, with an attempted proof of the last statement that is essentially based on your hints (feel free to comment on it :) ). Still, the main statement still eludes me, even if I have some thoughts about it (again, feel free to comment on it). Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Did: Just to point that I have been thinking for quite a while about this proble, and I have realized how far I was in my edit with a reference to the Riesz Representation Theorem. Still, after quite a bit of looking around (Rudin's text), I don't see how it works, so I finally put a carefully thought bounty.

Comment: You seem to want to "prove" your result by relocating it as part of a big theorem. It happens that a one-line proof based on my specific indications would yield it right away much more easily (that is, a proof of (b), which was the only subject of your initial question, I believe).

Comment: @Did: Actually, it could be said that my original question was ambiguous in the sense that it concerned part **(a)** and **(b)**, *plus* the specific statement in braces from the quotation. As far as I got, your feedback concerned only this, and the proof in the question works on your extensive hint. From this, question **(1)** is if the actual "proof" is correct or not. Still, I don't see the main statement in the quotation, and I really thought about it (also by reading) without seeing what really happens, and I would love to. Hence, my questions **(2)**-**(3)**-**(4)**  with the Bounty. :)

Comment: No answer was posted so this does not matter much in the present case, but know that changing the question's scope like you did is, understandably, frowned upon on the site.

Comment: @Did. I do see and I understand (and I agree) completely. Just to explain my behavior , I did it just for three reasons: 1) the original question was rather broad (as exemplified from the title, which hints at part (a) and (b)), even tough it was pointing more to the statement in braces; 2) as you pointed out, no question has been given; 3) strongly related to (2), given the absence of an answer, I wanted to make explicit the open scope of the question (which I also think can be interesting for a broader audience than myself alone), without creating an unuseful duplicate.

Comment: Yep, I had guessed so.

Comment: @Did: Two things. Regarding my question **(1)**, it is not about the hint you gave me, but rather how I actually wrote it (having no feedbacks in general on my proofs, I am always afraid of messing up even the most straighforward hints!). The second is that I found on the wiki page on Locally Convex TVS something related to my question. It seems to me that the space I call $\mathcal{M}$ is homeomorphic to $L_0$. Is it right? Because, then the problem would end up in showing that $L_0$ is homeomorphic to $L^p$ with $0<p<1$ (which should be the case). Thanks a lot for your helpfulness!

Answer (score 2):

First a note on terminology: The more widely used convention is that a Fréchet space is a locally convex complete metrisable vector space. Complete metrisable vector spaces that are not (necessarily) locally convex may then be called $F$-spaces.

Next we have a problem in the substance matter. On the space of all measurable functions,

$$\rho \colon (f,g) \mapsto \int_0^1 \min \{ 1 , \lvert f(t) - g(t)\rvert\}\,dt$$

is not a metric, only a pseudometric. If two measurable functions are equal almost everywhere, we have $\rho (f,g) = 0$. To get a metric, we have to divide out the space $\mathcal{N}$ of almost everywhere vanishing functions. But if we do that, then $[f] \mapsto f(0)$ is not a well-defined map on $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$.

The same applies to the space $L_0$. Since for any $a \geqslant 0$ we have the inequalities

$$\frac{1}{2}\min \{ 1, a\} \leqslant \frac{a}{1+a} \leqslant \min \{ 1, a\},$$

we see that the pseudometrics $\rho$ and $d$ on the space of all measurable functions are Lipschitz-equivalent, in particular they induce the same uniform structure and hence the same topology. Thus we can in the following ignore $L_0$, everything said about $\mathcal{M}$ resp. $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ applies - with perhaps minor changes in the formulation of inequalities involving the pseudometrics and of proofs - also to $L_0$ resp. $L_0/\mathcal{N}$.

However, there is no big problem in endowing $\mathcal{M}$ with the topology induced by the pseudometric $\rho$, it just isn't a Hausdorff space then. If we do that, the linear functional $f \mapsto f(0)$ is well-defined and discontinuous, and the answer to your question **1)** is "Yes, your proof is correct". Although in that setting we could just take $f = 0$ and $g = \chi_{\{0\}}$, then we have $\rho (f,g) = 0$ but $f(0) = 0 \neq 1 = g(0)$.

#### $(\mathcal{M},\rho)$ is a complete pseudometric topological vector space

First, we need to prove that $\rho$ is a pseudometric. It is clear that we have $\rho (f,f) = 0$ for all $f\in \mathcal{M}$, and $\rho (f,g) \geqslant 0$ for all $f,g \in \mathcal{M}$. The symmetry $\rho (f,g) = \rho(g,f)$ follows from $\lvert -x\rvert = \lvert x\rvert$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$), and the triangle inequality from the pointwise triangle inequality

$$\min \{ 1, \lvert a-c\rvert\} \leqslant \min \{ 1, \lvert a-b\rvert\} + \min \{ 1, \lvert b-c\rvert\}.$$

Next we note that $\rho$ is translation-invariant, for all $f,g,h\in \mathcal{M}$ we have $\rho (f,g) = \rho (f+h,g+h)$, and from that we deduce the (uniform) continuity of addition:

\begin{align}
\rho (f+g,f_0+g_0) &= \rho\bigl((f-f_0) + (g-g_0),0\bigr)\\
&\leqslant \rho\bigl((f-f_0) + (g - g_0), g-g_0\bigr) + \rho(g-g_0,0)\\
&= \rho(f-f_0,0) + \rho(g-g_0,0)\\
&= \rho(f,f_0) + \rho(g,g_0),
\end{align}

so $B_{\varepsilon/2}(f_0) + B_{\varepsilon/2}(g_0) \subset B_{\varepsilon}(f_0 + g_0)$.

To establish the continuity of scalar multiplication at the point $(\lambda_0,f_0) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathcal{M}$, we write

$$\lambda f - \lambda_0 f_0 = (\lambda - \lambda_0) f_0 + \lambda(f-f_0).$$

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, we want to find $\delta,\eta > 0$ such that $\rho(\lambda f,\lambda_0 f_0) < \varepsilon$ whenever $\lvert\lambda - \lambda_0\rvert < \delta$ and $\rho(f,f_0) < \eta$. If we require $\delta \leqslant 1$, then it follows that $\lvert\lambda\rvert < 1 + \lvert\lambda_0\rvert$, and hence

$$\rho(\lambda f, \lambda f_0) \leqslant \max\{ 1, \lvert\lambda\rvert\}\cdot \rho(f,f_0) \leqslant (1 + \lvert\lambda_0\rvert)\cdot \rho(f,f_0).$$

Thus if we choose $\eta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+\lvert\lambda_0\rvert)}$, we have

$$\rho(\lambda f,\lambda_0 f_0) < \rho\bigl((\lambda-\lambda_0) f_0,0\bigr) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$

if $\rho(f,f_0) < \eta$ and $\lvert\lambda - \lambda_0\rvert < 1$.

It remains to show that we can choose $\delta \in (0,1]$ so that $\lvert\lambda - \lambda_0\rvert < \delta$ implies $\rho\bigl((\lambda - \lambda_0)f_0,0\bigr) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. If that were not possible, there would exist a sequence $(\mu_n)$ with $\mu_n \to 0$ and $\rho(\mu_n f_0,0) \geqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n$. But $g_n(t) = \min \{ 1, \lvert \mu_n f_0(t)\rvert\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions with $0 \leqslant g_n(t) \leqslant 1$ for all $t$ and $g_n(t) \to 0$ for all $t$. The dominated convergence theorem asserts that

$$\rho(\mu_n f_0,0) = \int_0^1 g_n(t)\,dt \to 0,$$

contradicting our assumption. Hence scalar multiplication is continuous at $(\lambda_0, f_0)$.

So the topology induced by $\rho$ makes $\mathcal{M}$ a topological vector space.

Next, let's show completeness. It suffices to show that every Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, since Cauchy sequences converge to all of their cluster points (and since we have a single pseudometric, it suffices to consider Cauchy sequences rather than Cauchy filters/Cauchy nets). Before proving the completeness, we note that pointwise almost everywhere convergence of a sequence of measurable functions implies $\rho$-convergence by the dominated convergence theorem.

Now let $(f_n)$ be a $\rho$-Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{M}$. By extracting a subsequence, we may assume that $\rho(f_n, f_{n+1}) < 4^{-n}$ for all $n$. Then we define $A_n = \{ t \in [0,1] : \lvert f_n(t) - f_{n+1}(t)\rvert \geqslant 2^{-n}\}$ and note

$$4^{-n} > \rho(f_n, f_{n+1}) \geqslant \int_{A_n} \min \{ 1, \lvert f_n(t) - f_{n+1}(t)\rvert\}\,dt \geqslant \int_{A_n} 2^{-n}\,dt = 2^{-n}\lambda(A_n),$$

whence $\lambda(A_n) < 2^{-n}$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Since $\sum \lambda(A_n) < +\infty$, the Borel-Cantelli lemma asserts that $E = \limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} A_n = \{ t \in [0,1] : t\in A_n \text{ for infinitely many } n\}$ is a null set. For all $t\in [0,1]\setminus E$, the sequence $\bigl(f_n(t)\bigr)$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence

$$f(t) = \begin{cases} \quad 0 &, t \in E \\ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(t) &, t \notin E \end{cases}$$

is a measurable function, and $f_n \to f$ pointwise almost everywhere, so $\rho(f_n,f) \to 0$, which shows the completeness.

#### Existence of continuous linear functionals

If $E$ is a topological vector space, and $\lambda\neq 0$ a continuous linear functional on $E$, then $E$ possesses nonempty open convex proper subsets - for every nonempty open convex proper subset $U$ of the scalar field (be that $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), $\lambda^{-1}(U)$ is a nonempty open convex proper subset. Conversely, the Hahn-Banach theorem asserts the existence of a nonzero continuous linear functional on $E$ if $E$ possesses a nonempty open convex proper subset.

Since translations are homeomorphisms in topological vector spaces and they preserve convexity, the nonexistence of nonempty open convex proper subsets is equivalent to the assertion that the convex hull of every neighbourhood of $0$ is the whole space. This is often the easiest way to prove that a TVS admits no nonzero continuous linear functional.

Let $f\in \mathcal{M}$ be arbitrary. For $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, we define $I^{(n)}_k = \bigl(\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}\bigr]$ for $2 \leqslant k \leqslant n$ and $I^{(n)}_1 = \bigl[0,\frac{1}{n}\bigr]$. Also, we set $g^{(n)}_k = n\cdot f\cdot \chi_{I^{(n)}_k}$.

Then $\rho(g^{(n)}{k},0) \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$, and the identity $f = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}\cdot g^{(n)}_k$ shows $f \in \operatorname{co} B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ when we pick $n > 1/\varepsilon$.

The argument for the $L^p$ spaces with $0 < p < 1$ is similar, but we need to choose the partitions of $[0,1]$ based on $f$. Since

$$x \mapsto \int_0^x \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt$$

is a continuous nondecreasing function, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ we find $0 = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsc < x_{n-1} < x_n = 1$ with

$$\int_0^{x_k} \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt = \frac{k}{n}\int_0^1 \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt.$$

Similar to the above, we define $I^{(n)}_k = (x_{k-1}, x_k]$ (resp. $I^{(n)}_1 = [0,x_1]$) and $g^{(n)}_k = n \cdot f \cdot \chi_{I^{(n)}_k}$. Then

$$\int_0^1 \lvert g^{(n)}_k(t)\rvert^p\,dt = n^{p-1}\int_0^1 \lvert f(t)\rvert^p\,dt,$$

and since $p-1 < 0$, we can choose $n$ so large that $f = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} g^{(n)}_k$ represents $f$ as a convex combination of elements of $B_{\varepsilon}(0)$, whatever $\varepsilon > 0$ is given.

#### Nonexistence of isomorphisms between $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ and $L^p$

I don't know whether any of these spaces are homeomorphic, but if we restrict our attention to linear homeomorphisms (aka isomaorphisms in the category of topological vector spaces [over $\mathbb{R}$ resp. $\mathbb{C}$]), which is probably intended, we can see that $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ is not isomorphic to $L^p$ for any $p$ (nor is $\mathcal{M}$ isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}^p([0,1])$, the space of all $p$-integrable measurable functions).

Namely, all $L^p$ (resp. $\mathcal{L}^p$) spaces are locally bounded, while $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ (resp. $\mathcal{M}$) is not locally bounded.

By the $p$-homogeneity of the distance on $L^p$ (resp. $\mathcal{L}^p$), we have $c\cdot B_r(0) = B_{c^p\cdot r}(0)$ for all $c > 0$, so all balls with finite radius in $L^p$ ($\mathcal{L}^p$) are bounded [in the sense of TVSs].

To see that $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ ($\mathcal{M}$) is not locally bounded, let $0 < r_1 < s < r_2 \leqslant 1$. Then we have $\rho(\lambda\cdot \chi_{[0,s]},0) \leqslant s < r_2$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, so $B_{r_2}(0)$ contains the line $\mathbb{R}\cdot \chi_{[0,s]}$, hence every multiple $c\cdot B_{r_2}(0)$ with $c\neq 0$ also contains that whole line. But $\rho(\chi_{[0,s]},0) = s > r_1$, so $B_{r_1}(0)$ does not contain the whole line, hence no ball $B_r(0)$ is bounded in $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ ($\mathcal{M}$).

Since linear homeomorphisms preserve local boundedness, it follows that $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ is not (topologically) isomorphic to any $L^p$ space.

#### Answers to the further questions

**1)** was already mentioned, $(f,g) \mapsto \int_0^1 \min \{ 1, \lvert f(t) - g(t)\rvert\}\,dt$ is not actually a metric but only a pseudometric on $\mathcal{M}$, and on the associated metric TVS $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$, the map $[f] \mapsto f(0)$ is not well-defined. Your proof is correct as a proof that the linear functional $f \mapsto f(0)$ on $(\mathcal{M},\rho)$ is not continuous.

**2)** I'm not sure what exactly "Is it possible to prove part (a) in different ways" is asking.

If it's about the fact that $(\mathcal{M},\rho)$ is a complete pseudometric topological vector space, then of course there are possible variations in the proof, but I don't see essentially different ways to go about it. In particular, "one less constructive, and another one more constructive, with an actual $f \in \mathcal{M}$ to which an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(f_n) \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ converges", for the completeness, one needs to consider an arbitrary Cauchy sequence, so one can't really have something concrete.

If it's about the nonexistence of nonzero continuous linear functionals, we again face the situation that we need to deal with all nonzero linear functionals and show that they aren't continuous. Since there are too many linear functionals, and they can't be easily described, we can't be concrete here either, although for every given nonzero linear functional it is probably not too difficult to explicitly show its discontinuity with a concrete example.

**3)** As mentioned, $\mathcal{M}$ is the same as $L_0$, the two pseudometrics are Lipschitz-equivalent, so showing that one doesn't admit continuous nonzero linear functionals shows that the other doesn't admit them either. Since $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{N}$ is not isomorphic (as TVSs) to any $L^p$, we can't directly prove (b) using Rudin's proof of the corresponding feature of the $L^p$ spaces, but we can use the same idea. In fact, as it turns out the construction is slightly easier for $\mathcal{M}$.

**4)** See above. We cannot directly use Rudin's proof, but the proof of (b) is an easy modification. The proof of completeness is a little different than for the $L^p$ spaces, because due to the capping of the integrand at $1$, it is not as easy to see that an absolutely convergent series in $\mathcal{M}$ must be pointwise convergent almost everywhere, we invoked the Borel-Cantelli lemma for that.

Comment: Wow... I mean, I am speechless. This is amazing! Really (really!) thanks a lot! Considering that you simply put in this answers (more or less) two months of my recent self-studies (most probably, not properly internalised... as your answer is showing me), just give me a bit to print it and try to read and reread it to get (hopefully) most of the nuances.

Comment: Feel free to ask for elaborations on any points that are unclear after thinking about them for a while.

Comment: First of all, let me write a huge thank! After having spent quite some time on your answer, I can say this is really amazing. Basically, you put in this answer all the things I have studied recently, literally making them alive (common problem when you are self-thaught... often things stay dead on the page). This answer for me is basically a tutorial on analysis, and – actually – an amazing tutorial. In the following there are some numbered questions, that could be followed by some others in the very next days (it takes me some time to digest thing). Again, really thanks a lot!

Comment: **1)** I see why you take the quotient spaces $\mathcal{M}/ \mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{p}/ \mathcal{N}$ (which should be equal to $L^p$) [*of course, correct me if I am wrong, but I think you are using the distinction made by Dudley in chapter 5*]: The point is that we really work with equivalence classes of functions. Still, I don't see why you use $\mathcal{N}$, i.e. the space of almost everywhere vanishing functions. Could you clarify a bit on this? (most probably it is trivial, but I really could not see it)

Comment: **2)** Reference question: You use the expression "Lipschitz-equivalent" to refer to what I would call "strongly equivalent metrics" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics). Where is your expression used (which books)? Is it actually the standard expression in the field?

Comment: **3)** When you write "we note that pointwise almost everywhere convergence of a sequence of measurable functions implies
$\rho$-convergence by the dominated convergence theorem", are you referring to the following result (or a good friend of it)? *"Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^1$. Suppose that $f_n \to f$ a.e. and that $| f_n | < g$ a.e.for all n, where $g \in L^1$. Then, $f \in L^1$ and $\int | f_n - f| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. That is, $|| f_n - f ||_1 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$*" .

Comment: **Small Aside:** My question (2) essentially comes from having completely overlooked the previous lemma, and the characterization you use of *Cauchyness* (essentially the all paragraph "Next, let's show completeness... convergence theorem"). The problem is that I was thinking about – naively – proving the completeness by using the very definition of Cauchy sequence. Hence, (a) )either by constructing the $f$ to which an arbitrary $(f_n)$  converge, or (b) by contradiction. [I know that (a) is essentially wrong, but I still have to properly see why it really is wrong. :) ]

Comment: @Kolmin **1)** Yes, $L^p = \mathcal{L}^p/\mathcal{N}$. I don't know Dudley's book, but it's almost certainly the same distinction. We use $\mathcal{N}$ because that is what the integral cannot distinguish from $0$; we have $\mathcal{N} = \{ f : \rho(f,0) = 0\} = \{ f : d(f,0) = 0\} = \{ f : \int \lvert f\rvert\,d\lambda = 0\}$. By translation-invariance, $\rho(f,g) = 0 \iff f-g \in \mathcal{N} \iff \int \lvert f-g\rvert\,d\lambda = 0$. Dividing out $\mathcal{N}$ gives us the associated Hausdorff space. In terms of topological vector spaces, note that a TVS is Hausdorff if and only if …

Comment: … singleton sets are closed. Thus a quotient $E/F$, where $E$ is a TVS and $F$ a subspace is Hausdorff if and only if $F$ is closed. So when we have a non-Hausdorff TVS $E$, we get the associated Hausdorff space by dividing out $\overline{\{0\}}$, the smallest of all closed subspaces. In our spaces $\mathcal{M}$ resp. $\mathcal{L}^p$, we have $\overline{\{0\}} = \mathcal{N}$. The pseudometrics on these spaces cannot distinguish two functions if and only if they are almost everywhere equal, hence one identifies such functions.

Comment: **2)** Yes, what I call Lipschitz-equivalence is called strong equivalence in that wikipedia article. A metric (or pseudometric, more generally a family of pseudometrics) induces several things on a space: 1. A topology; if two metrics (families of pseudometrics) induce the same topology, they are topologically equivalent. 2. A uniform structure; if two metrics (families of pseudometrics) induce the same uniform structure, they are uniformly equivalent. 3. A Lipschitz structure; as long as a single space and structure are considered, that's not interesting beyond the uniform structure, but …

Comment: … when we have more than one space, or more than one such structure on one space, we can consider Lipschitz-continuous maps, which have even nicer properties than merely uniformly continuous functions. If two families of pseudometrics induce the same Lipschitz structure (the identity map is Lipschitz-continuous in both directions), then they are Lipschitz equivalent. I'm not sure how widespread that terminology is,

Comment: I learned about Lipschitz structures from Laurent Schwartz' book _Analyse II, Topologie Générale et Analyse Fonctionelle_, which is probably long out of print and hard to obtain. I don't remember whether he used the term Lipschitz equivalent or not.

Comment: **3)** Yes, that's the dominated convergence theorem. When we have a sequence $(f_n)$ converging pointwise a.e. to $f$, then $\min \{ 1, \lvert f_n(t) - f(t)\rvert\}$ resp. $\frac{\lvert f_n(t) - f(t)\rvert}{1 + \lvert f_n(t) - f(t)\rvert}$ are dominated by the constant $1$, and converge to $0$ almost everywhere, hence the sequence of integrals, that is $\rho(f_n,f)$ resp. $d(f_n,f)$, converges to $0$. We can't apply the DCT to $\lvert f_n(t) - f(t)\rvert$, since that need not be integrable for any $n$, and if it happens to be integrable, it need not be dominated by an integrable function.

Comment: But fortunately we're not interested in $\lvert f_n - f\rvert$ itself, only in $\rho(f_n,f)$ (resp. $d(f_n,f)$), and that is nicely under control. It's worth noting that pointwise a.e. convergence is strictly stronger than $\rho$-convergence, but, as in the $\mathcal{L}^p$ case, every convergent sequence has a pointwise a.e. convergent subsequence.